# VS2010 Remove grid lines in WPF Design View

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, settings

Is there a way to remove the annoying grid lines in the design view of Visual Studio 2010? Or at least style them to fade them off?

I'm not referring to the *Grid* component, but to the *design view* in WPF which draws visual lines over and around every components, making screens look like a soup in design view.

Comment: Do you mean 4 Anchors around the control like http://www.softinsight.com/bnoyes/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/VisualStudio2008WPFCiderDesignerFirstImp_6BC5/Cider_thumb.png (around the button in the top right corner)  or Horizontal and vertical GridLines in the designer surface like in Blend like http://media.techtarget.com/digitalguide/images/Misc/20100816_creatingGraph2.gif?

Comment: yeah the light blue lines in your first link.

Comment: The answer should be: Click the Design pane, then press F9.  Or click the Design pane, then click Design, then Show Handles.  Probably most people miss this because they have the coding pane selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can derive from Grid and build design-time meta-data assembly with it as described on this msdn blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/01/13/wpf-silverlight-design-time-code-sharing-part-i.aspx#required

The reason I suggest deriving from Grid is because you want the designer to load new meta data for the type. Hopefully this implementation will override default behaviour although I have not tried myself.

Can I ask why you want to make this change? I am interested.

Comment: Because I'd like the design view to be as accurate as possible. I design pixel perfect (ok, dpi perfect) screens and those light blue lines just make so much clutter it's impossible to see what you're doing.

Comment: If it were me I would type directly into the xaml for accurate Height/Width values but I do agree that it would be nice not to have too! 

Expression Blend lets you do it graphically. I recommend it for any serious design work in wpf!

Comment: I down voted this answer. The answer should be: Click the Design pane, then press F9. Or click the Design pane, then click Design, then Show Handles. Probably most people miss this because they have the coding pane selected.

Comment: @theMaxx similar to DefenestrationDay's answer? I agree.

Comment: @Gusdor  Would you update your answer?  I think it would be more helpful.  Many people don't read the comments and only read the accepted answer.  I would rather up vote the answer than down vote it.

Answer (score 18):

In Blend, if you disable `Show Handles` (in View > Show Handles, or F9), you can turn off those stupid blue lines.

Answer (score -1):

You say not the Grid component but those blue lines are part of the Grid control and you can simple drag them off the screen to remove them.  I do not see any other light blue lines in that first link.  If the problem is when you are running the app then uncheck the 'show gridlines' property for the Grid in VS2010.

Comment: You cant drag those off the screen!!!! it WILL F up your grid. Those are the visual representations of your Row and Column definitions and as such, are two-way bound to them.

Comment: When I remove the grid lines VS automatically updates the controls and my layout stays correct.  Maybe there is another positioning option which might cause it to break?